# Override a method in an explicitly typed self referenced trait

Tags: scala

I have some troubles with Scala and explicitly typed self referenced trait. I have two trait and one implementation :

```scala
trait A {
  def print(msg: String): Unit
}
class AImpl extends A {
  def print(msg: String): Unit = println(msg + " from A")
}
trait B { self: A =>
  override def print(msg: String): Unit = self.print(msg + " from B")
}
val a = new AImpl with B
a.print("Hello, World!")
```

I want `a.print("Hello, World!")` print `Hello, World! from B from A`. It compiles without any error but a StackOverflowError is thrown at runtime.

Here is a [Scastie](http://scastie.org/3290) I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is effectively this:

```
trait B {
  def print(msg: String): Unit = this.print(msg + " from B") //Recursively build up stack until overflow
}
```

Remember that `self` is just an alias for `this` and not `super`. Additionally, since `A` is a self type, it's not a super type of `B` so you can't call `super.print`. So you've successfully overridden `print` in `AImpl` but you're not calling the  `print` impl that you've created.

**UPDATE**

To achieve what you want you need to extend `A` instead of using it as a self type (sorry but you can't do what you want with self types):

```
  trait B extends A {
    abstract override def print(msg: String): Unit = super.print(msg + " from B")
  }
```

Comment: So is there any way yo achieve what i want ?

Comment: @Blackrush sorry but you can't do what you want with self types